# Getting 'Service_InternalServerError' when creating application through Graph API in Azure AD

Tags: ruby, azure, automation, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create application in Azure AD programatically.
I added initial app in management portal and granted permissions to Graph Api and Active directory (Directory read/write in both).

First I acquire authorization code, sample url formation is below:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize')
  uri.query_values = {
    response_type: 'code',
    response_mode: 'form_post',
    client_id: <Application ID>,
    redirect_uri: <Redirect URI>,   
    resource: 'https://graph.windows.net/',
    state: <UUID>,
  }
```

Afterwards I get auth token through bellow request:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id,
                          client_secret,
                          :site => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
                          :authorize_url => '/common/oauth2/authorize',
                          :token_url => '/common/oauth2/token')

auth_token = client.auth_code.get_token(auth_code,
                                 :redirect_uri => redirect_uri,
                                 :scope => 'openid'
```

Finally i can make graph api call to to applications endpoint to add an app:

```
graph_url = 'https://graph.windows.net/<TENANT ID>/applications?api-version=1.6'
body = {
  'identifierUris' => ['<URI>'],
  'availableToOtherTenants' => true,
  'homepage' => <Home PAGE>,
  'replyURLs' => <SOME REPLY URL>,
  'displayName' => <APP DISPLAY NAME>,
}
headers = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json','Authorization' =>  "Bearer #{auth_token.token}"}
conn = Faraday.new(graph_url, {headers: headers})
res = conn.post graph_url, body.to_json
```

In response I get bellow error which is not very descriptive and not sure what's wrong:

```
{"odata.error"=>{"code"=>"Service_InternalServerError", "message"=>{"lang"=>"en", "value"=>"Encountered an internal server error."}}}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem, getting internal error when trying to create App.
Be careful when forming 'body' for http request. I was adding extra '/' at the end of url in 'replyUrls' property. Also adding data type for each property is important. Here is the sample request that worked for me:

```
body = {
  "odata.type" => "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Application",
  "identifierUris" => ["https://mynamehere.com/#{someidentifier}"],
  "identifierUris@odata.type" => "Collection(Edm.String)",
  "availableToOtherTenants" => true,
  "homepage" => 'https://myhomepage.com',
  "replyURLs" => ["http://localhost:3000/someUrl"],
  "replyURLs@odata.type" => "Collection(Edm.String)",
  "displayName" => 'This is my app',   
 }
```

Here is the link to blog that was helpful:

http://blog.mszcool.com/index.php/2016/06/a-deep-dive-into-azure-ad-multi-tenant-apps-oauthopenidconnect-flows-admin-consent-and-azure-ad-graph-api/

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this issue. I have found in the past that a really easy way to avoid issues like this is to first do a 'GET' on a similar object, then modify that object to contain the new properties you want, and then use that for your POST. For example, I would create an app using the Azure Portal, and then use the skeleton of that app to then create new apps in my POST request. Another tip could be to use Fiddler to capture the HTTP traffic of PowerShell, or another service which can create applications using graph, and then use that to help create your body.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will keep it in mind for future!